# How to configure vs code for running individual tests and integration tests in a maven quarkus kotlin project?

Tags: maven, kotlin, visual-studio-code, quarkus

How to configure tasks.json for running and debugging @QuarkusTest tests in vs code in a maven project that uses Kotlin?